# execute multiple query with temp table in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query, to copy a row within a table and alter a few columns.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS 
       SELECT * 
         FROM table1 
        WHERE offertecode = '1c12a23453453458e492230df420972'; 

UPDATE temp_table 
   SET offertecode = '82a24c7da2342423424351804ab043', 
       id = NULL, 
       reference = '[COPY] subject'; 

INSERT INTO table1 
       SELECT * 
         FROM temp_table; 

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table;
```

This works perfectly fine in phpmyadmin, but I cant get it to work from within PHP, I get an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'UPDATE temp_table SET offertecode = '82a24c7da2342423424351804ab043', 
id = ' at line 5
```

Can anyone help me on how to execute this query in PHP?

PHP code:

```
$mysqli->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS 
           SELECT * 
             FROM table1 
            WHERE offertecode = '1c12a23453453458e492230df420972'; 

UPDATE temp_table 
   SET offertecode = '82a24c7da2342423424351804ab043', 
       id = NULL, 
       reference = '[COPY] subject'; 

INSERT INTO table1 
       SELECT * 
         FROM temp_table; 

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table;");
```

Thanks!

Comment: PHP code is not much more then the query wrapped in a mysqli->query(); But someone commented earlier (I think it is removed) that it should be done in multiple statements. That worked, but id still love for it to work in one query.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address the mysqli problem (which is having four statements in a single query).  You should run those separately.  But, you don't need four statements.  Just do:

```
insert into table1(offertecode, id, reference, <rest of columns>)
    select '82a24c7da2342423424351804ab043' as offertecode, NULL as id, '[COPY] subject' as reference,
           <rest of columns>
    from table1
    where offertecode = '1c12a23453453458e492230df420972';
```

An `insert . . . select` statement can refer to the same table in both parts.  Even in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $mysqli->multi_query. The basic answer is you cannot run multiple queries using $mysqli->query. The syntax error is due to a second query trying to to be run under $mysqli->query which only allows one main query. That query can contain sub or nested queries, but only one main query. To run multiple queries you have to use $mysqli->multi_query